# recursive function in R applied to a vector

Tags: r, recursion

i'd like to know the most efficient (think code AND speed, in case i'd be running it on very very large vectors or objects) to compute a recursive function on an vector. (to compute S[i] we just need S[k] up to k<=(i-1) and V[k] with k<=i )

a simple example would be given a num vector v of length N, to return a vector
S where S[i] is the sum of the the first i elements of v.

in this particular case, a (`for`) loop is quite ugly...and (*edited*) so not efficient
doing something like

```
myfun <- function(i){sum(length_table[1:i])}
        S <- sapply(v,myfun))
```

is not good because of many unnecessary calculations ...

any suggestions ?

EDIT:
to me there is not much too much difference between iterative and recursive.
i didn't know about the cumsum function which solves the problem in this particular case.

ok now let's have a more general case where we have a (num) function f which takes two (num) arguments so f(x,y) is also a num value. we need a num "seed" as well.
given a num vector v of length N,

i'd like to construct the vector U defined by

```
U[1] = f(v[1],seed)
U[2] = f(v[2],U[1])
U[3] = f(v[3],U[2])...

U[N] = f(v[N],U[N-1])
```

is there a nice efficient way to do that without looping ?

Comment: Are you looking for `f <- function(v, i) cumsum(v[1:i])`?

Comment: your question is unclear: if cumulative sum is just an example (with a well known solution, se Pierre's comment), what is your actual problem?

Comment: Agree with both comments. Additionally the premise of hte question that recursive solutions would be vectorizes is wrong. R is well-known for good support of vectorized solutions and poor support of recursive ones. Furthermore the illustrated code is not really recursive but iterative.

Comment: A more efficient way usually needs to be tailored to a specific problem. Please state a specific problem.

Comment: The new problem statement does meet my definition of recursive (having calculations that require results of prior computation), and `for`-loops are the way to do such problems. If your goal is coding compactness, then look at the `Reduce` function with 'accumulate' set to TRUE, but I do not think it improves performance (or readability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to implement this in R (and while Reduce might seem to be more elegant, my experience is that it is more prone to (my) confusion):

```
> y <- numeric(); y[1] <- 1; for( i in 2:10 ){ y[i] <- 3+y[i-1]*2}
> y
 [1]    1    5   13   29   61  125  253  509 1021 2045

> Reduce( function(x,y){ y= 3+ x*2}, 1:10, accumulate=TRUE)
 [1]    1    5   13   29   61  125  253  509 1021 2045
```